# Installed Ubuntu Desktop using a partition on my extra HDD but Win8 keeps booting instead?

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, windows-8

I just installed Ubuntu on a HDD and when I restart my computer, it goes straight to Windows 8 login. I have 256GB SSD (where my Win8 and other important programs are installed), and another 2TB HDD. I have the HDD split into two 1TB partitions. The first 1TB I save all my non essential software and the second is empty. So I want to install Ubuntu on my second 1TB partition.

These are the steps I followed -

1. Right clicked on my `Other E:` drive and clicked shrink and making a new partition for 100GB for my linux to be stored.
2. Then I restarted my computer with Ubuntu CD and clicked `Install Ubuntu`
3. Clicked continue until I reached where I want to install Ubuntu.
4. I clicked `Something else`
5. Clicked on `free space` -> then `+`
6. Size i put `2048MB` for Use as I put `Swap area` then I clicked ok.
7. Then I made a root partition by clicking on the rest of `free space`
8. The size I chose whatever is left in the free space. For mount point I chose the root `/`
9. For the boot loader installation drop down I chose `/dev/sdb ATA ST2000DM001-1CH1 (2.0 TB)` (My Windows 8 loader is on /dev/sda1. Do I have to choose sda for my ubuntu boot loader installation as well?)

I continued with the installation, it asked me to remove my CD from drive and restart. I did so, but it always goes straight to Win8 and doesn't ask me what I'd like to boot!

Just for reference, my fast startup is turned off.

Does anyone know why I might be having this issue and how to solve it? I've tried a lot of different things...How do you even delete the linux I just installed that I can't access? Can I go to Disk Management and Delete that partition as a whole?

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Sounds like you might have an issue with Grub. Do you remember getting any kind of error suggesting that grub, or the boot loader didn't install correctly?

Comment: No I never got any messages regarding Grub. I noticed that I chose sdb for my boot loader installation and my win8 loader is on sda. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I think that your secondary hard drive is just set to boot after the primary (Win 8) one. Fix this in your BIOS settings, by putting the secondary hard drive above the first in the boot priority.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem!!

Out of the total 100GB partition I made, I used 2GB `swap area` and made another root partition for the rest of the space for `Ext4`. My problem was, at the drop down, to install the linux loader, I kept checking the `sdb` which is my HDD. But my windows 8 loader was on my `sda`.

Even though you want to put linux on a different hard drive than your other operating system, your loader has to be the same location as your original OS. In this case, my Win8 loader was in `/dev/sda` so I have to put my linux loader in `sda`. This has to be the same.

Sorry for the troubles, but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a bootloader like [GRUB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB). For now, try to go into your BIOS settings (F12 usually does this) and choose the default boot disk.

Comment: I figured out the issue and posted as an answer, thank you for your help though :)